# Converting android app to ios

Tags: android, ios

I have one simple question,  that is can I convert my android .apk app into ios using any software? If yes, then please give me the name of that software. If any alternative method for that please guide me.

Comment: At least until this date, there is not such a simple way to convert android native app to iOS version, unless cross-platform approachs

Answer (score 3):

Google has a tool to convert the back-end, nothing for front-end though

http://www.xda-developers.com/google-tool-helps-developers-port-android-apps-to-ios/

Answer (score 3):

There is a new startup that clains to convert the APK to IOS.

It's called [MechDome](https://www.mechdome.com/index.html).

The goal is very simple and attractable:

> Reduce time to market by eliminating cross-platform development. Automatically convert your existing Android apps to high-fidelity, native iOS apps.

Comment: you might as well hire 3 or even 4 cross-platform developers

Comment: MechDome is down as of 30/03/2021 [link](http://mechdome.com)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing out there that would convert apk into ios app. To my knowledge there is also nothing out there that could translate android code to IOS. The operation is simply too complex for a simple tool to manage.

However, there are tools you could use to make your apps (developed by you) work across multiple platforms. I'm sure there are more, but here are 2 of them I found in minutes (look into them if you are interested): [Apportable](https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/apportable), [Phonegap](https://build.phonegap.com/) ([discontinued as of 2020/03](https://blog.phonegap.com/update-for-customers-using-phonegap-and-phonegap-build-cc701c77502c). It was made obsolete by ProgressiveWebApps - PWA).

In past decade or so WebApps have been picking up for anything that is not too graphically demanding as they can run on anything that has a Web Browser. With this style devs pretty much open their website in a platform-specific executable and it looks like an app.

As for your existing app depending on complexity of your software you have to rewrite from a little to a lot of code to adapt to IOS APIs.

In short: No. Unless your app is build on multiplatform framework, converting means manual adaptation.

Comment: Why this links doesn't open?

Comment: @Hussien Fahmy it appears both projects moved to diffierent websites. I updated the links. Keep in mind Phonegap got discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

There is no known way to convert an android app to iOS. MechDome which is a Developer Tool that Automatically Converts Android Apps into iOS Apps seems to have stopped as of 30/03/2021. [link](https://www.mechdome.com/)

However if it is your plan to launch android and iOS app from one coding project, use Flutter which allows you to launch on both platforms simultaneously.

Flutter is Google’s mobile UI framework that provides a fast and expressive way for developers to build native apps on both iOS & Android, using a single codebase.

Get started here [link](https://flutter.dev/web)